# connecting to gmail with imap

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap

I'm trying to conncet to my gmail to download mails attachments.
I wrote the following code:

```
import imaplib

email_user = 'my_email@gmail.com'
email_pass = 'my_pass'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
mail.login(email_user, email_pass)
```

It throws and error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-945b3b5696e0> in <module>
----> 1 mail.login(email_user, email_pass)

c:\users\mikee\anaconda3\envs\gmail_attach\lib\imaplib.py in login(self, user, password)
    610         typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
    611         if typ != 'OK':
--> 612             raise self.error(dat[-1])
    613         self.state = 'AUTH'
    614         return typ, dat

error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'
```

I enabled less secure apps and IMAP in gmail settings, I also checked that my account is not blocked and unlocked CAPTCHA by this link: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: I faced the same problem and turning on _Less Secure App_ access worked for me. I had to do it a couple of times though, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Include exact text/explanation provided by gmail.  AFAIR google/gmail sometimes "blocks" logins until you log via www interface.

Comment: Create an apps password dont try to use the users actuall password https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Issue was resolved when I retried with a less secure apps after a few days. Still no idea what was wrong..

Answer (score 0):

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header

# IMAP server settings
IMAP_SERVER = "imap.youremailprovider.com"
IMAP_PORT = 993  # Standard IMAP SSL port

# Your email credentials
EMAIL_ADDRESS = "your_email@example.com"
EMAIL_PASSWORD = "your_password"

# Connect to the IMAP server
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT)

# Log in to your email account
imap.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

# Select the mailbox you want to watch (e.g., "INBOX")
mailbox = "INBOX"
imap.select(mailbox)

# Continuously check for new messages
while True:
    # Search for all unseen messages
    status, message_ids = imap.search(None, "UNSEEN")

    if status == "OK":
        message_ids = message_ids[0].split()
        for message_id in message_ids:
            # Fetch the email message
            status, message_data = imap.fetch(message_id, "(RFC822)")
            if status == "OK":
                # Parse the email message
                message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[0][1])
                subject, encoding = decode_header(message["Subject"])[0]
                if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                    subject = subject.decode(encoding or "utf-8")

                # Print the subject of the new email
                print(f"New email: {subject}")

    # Sleep for a while before checking again (e.g., every 60 seconds)
    import time
    time.sleep(60)

# Close the IMAP connection (optional)
imap.logout()
```

For Gmail you need to generate app password, follow this link: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

also you have to enable Imap for your Gmail account